# Google Developer Console - shows errors, where can I find those error messages

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

First, I apologize if this question has been asked before, or if the answer is simple.  The image below is a screen shot of my google dev console.  The second row has an application called Prospector App.  I am using the gcm to send push notification to my application.

When I first create a project and associate the app id in my phonegap application.  I am able to send and receive push notifications.  However, I am only able send a couple messages before they stop working.

I still get a success message like this

```
{"multicast_id":8850248775961364299,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1426185502223802%fdedd095f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

However, the notifications are never received on the device.  When this happens I notice the error number in the dev console increments, for what appears to be indefinitely.  I have another poject that has over 1k errors and counting.

My question is, where in the dev console are these error messages displayed?

[image: console error messages]

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: Do you change/use any of the following flags: collapse_key, TTL, delay_while_idle? And how much message traffic are we talking about?

Comment: I haven't tried using those flags yet. I  sent 10 or so notifications before I started having problems.

Comment: You should be able to see the specific error responses (500, 400, etc) under the Usage tab for the GCM API in the Developers Console.